# Counter example in topology

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

We known that every subspace of second countable space is second countable.  I was think if A is subspace of X and A is second countable space need to be the whole space is second countable space?  My statements is it true? Given an example plz

Comment: Have you considered the disjoint union of $A$ and an arbitrary topological space $B?$

Comment: I also highly advise the brain-bending book "Counterexamples in topology"

Comment: Please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Taking the time to [provide context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960), [pose a well-formatted question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) and use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) will generally improve the quality of the responses.

Comment: Your intuition should be that second countable is *small* in a certain sense, so subset of small is small, but superset of small doesn't have to be small. (For others reading: Yes, I know separable is also a kind of smallness and the first part no longer holds, at least not for topological spaces. But supersets of separable also don't have to be separable.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that whenever $A$ is a second countable subspace of a space $X$, then $X$ is also second countable. This proposition is logically equivalent to its contrapositive: if a space $X$ is not second countable, and $A\subseteq X$, then $A$ is not second countable. But this statement is clearly false, because every finite space is second countable, and there are spaces that are not second countable.

For instance, if $X$ is an uncountable space with the discrete topology, then $X$ is not second countable, but every countable subset of $X$ *is* second countable.